# Can someone help improve my Scala bisection answer? What is wrong?

Tags: java, scala, bisection

Implement the bisection method with the following specification:

```
Input: Function f, values low and high, error range epsilon.
`enter code here`Precondition: low<high, f(low) and f(high) diffs on their signs; that is,
either: f(low)>0 and f(high)<0
or:     f(low)<0 and f(high)>0.
Output: x where |f(x)| < epsilon.

Test your implementation with the following input values:
f(x) = 2x^3-3x^2-17x-50
low = -10
high = 10
epsilon = 1*10^(-6)  

Run your program, print out the solution (approximation) one each iteration
```

My code, not sure if this is correct:

```
object IntervalHalving {

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val low = -10
  val high = 10
  val epsilon = 1*10^(-6)

//top part seems correct//

//Not sure if i defined the function correctly//

  val f(x) = (x: Double) => x*x*x + x*x - 3*x-3

  val answer= halveTheInterval(f(x), low, high, epsilon)

   // print the answer
   println(answer)
}
```

Comment: Where's halveTheInterval? This code doesn't seem complete (or that much effort has gone into it). Post a minimal complete working example and more details of where you're having problems. "Not sure it's correct" is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about scala, but `val epsilon = 1*10^(-6)` is probably not what you think, but rather `xor(10,-6) = -16`. Use scientific notation instead: `val epsilon = 1.0e-6`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
scala> val epsilon = 1e-6
epsilon: Double = 1.0E-6
```

The `epsilon` defined above evaluates to `Int` with value `-16`  :)

And

```
scala> val f = (x: Double) => x*x*x + x*x - 3*x-3
f: Double => Double = <function1>
```

instead of `val f(x) = ...` Consider also for instance `Math.pow(x,3)`.

Recall to add a closing curly bracket for `object IntervalHalving` .